# I cannot use exfat formatted USB because of mount error

Tags: mount

> **Unable to mount DVN**
>   Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/leon/DVN:

Command-line Output:

```
mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/leon/DVN"'
exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install some software to handle exFAT.

Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and run:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

This worked for me. I have a card reader that came with my mom's Gateway computer with installed Ubuntu where it kept coming up with "error cannot mount volume". Now the card reader works fine for SD cards.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the following..

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Comment: It show "leon@leon-HP-450-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
[sudo] password for leon: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
leon@leon-HP-450-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a"

Comment: So after you run  sudo dpkg --configure -a, can you install it?

Comment: It didn't run, but i can format it by right-click on it's icon in launcher. After i had formatted it with NTFS, it's OK. Now,i can use it.